# Kinetic energy and de Broglie wavelength of an electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, units, wavelength

The question in the problem sheet reads

> The de Broglie wavelength of a *non-relativistic (nr)* electron with kinetic energy E$_{kin}$ can be written as
>
> $ \lambda_{nr} = \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{E_{kin}}} \;\; \text{Å} $
>
> In this formula $\delta$ is a unit-free constant, and the value of the energy $E_{kin}$ is entered in eV as a pure number. The answer comes out in Ångströms. Give the value of the constant $\delta$.

My first issue is that when I rearrange the terms in the equation above, I do not get that $\delta$ is unit-less:

$
\delta = \lambda_{nr}\sqrt{E_{kin}} = \frac{h}{p}\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{2m}} = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2m}}\\
= \left[ \frac{Js}{(kg)^{1/2}} \right] = \left[ \frac{kg\cdot m^2\cdot s}{s^2\cdot (kg)^{1/2}} \right]
$

where I have used the de Broglie wavelength of the electron and the formula $p^2/2m$ for its kinetic energy because I assume it is a free particle.

Answer (score 1):

You're right: the parameter $\delta$ is not dimensionless.  The question is telling you to choose units so that $E$ in eV gives you $\lambda$ in angstroms.  A better way to phrase this is “please report $\delta$ in units of $\rm Å\ eV^{1/2}$,” as you seem to have figured out.

The velocity/momentum information is hidden in the kinetic energy, which is outside of $\delta$.